# centos error: no package librrds-perl available

Tags: centos

I tried `yum install librrds-perl`

But I gave me this error:

no package librrds-perl available

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error, there is no package named librrds-perl in CentOS.

You probably want: `yum install rrdtool-perl`

Comment: After that webminstats still says: Can't locate RRDs.pm in @INC

Comment: Have you installed a version of perl other than the one shipping with the OS?  The rrdtool-perl package does in-fact have RRDs.pm:  `[root@noc01 ~]# yum whatprovides "*/RRDs.pm"
(snipped)
rrdtool-perl-1.3.8-6.el6.x86_64 : Perl RRDtool bindings
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/perl5/RRDs.pm`